# jQuery + CSS Manipulation using each()

Tags: jquery, each

I am trying to create a css menu. I would like to remove border and padding for every last
`li > a` element on the `child ul` tag. (sorry for confusing)

Here is the code for the menu

```
<ul id="nav">
                <li><a id="cat1" href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a id="cat2" href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                <li><a id="cat3" href="#">Menu 3</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1 - M3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a id="cat4" href="#">Menu 4</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2 - M3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3 - M3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4 - M3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

The code must remove border and padding for last elements that is

```
<li><a href="#">Sub Item 1 - M3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub Item 4 - M3</a></li>
```

Tried this but it takes off border for only sub item 4

```
$("#nav li ul").each(function(index) {
    $("#nav li ul > :last a").css('border','0 none');
    $("#nav li ul > :last a").css('padding','0');
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to call `.each`.
Instead, you can use the following selector:

```
$("#nav li ul > li:last-child a").css({ border: 0, padding: 0 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#nav li ul").each(function() {
    $("li:last a", this)
        .css('border', '0 none')
        .css('padding','0');
});
```